# SQL SELECT MAX is not working as intended

Tags: sql, select, group-by, max

```
SELECT hbgu.jid,
       hbgu.id AS id,
       hbgu.group_id,
       MAX (hbgu.parent_id) AS parent_id,
       hbgu.jid,
       d.name
FROM hms_bbr_group_user hbgu
LEFT JOIN hms_doctor d
    ON hbgu.jid = d.jid
WHERE hbgu.group_id = 113
GROUP BY hbgu.id, d.name
```

I have a `SELECT` statement above that is trying to only pick the maximum value of the column `parent_id`. In my case, I only want `parent_id = 114` because that is the highest value. My problem is that the values that are not the highest are showing up, what seems to be the issue?

[image: 1]

**UPDATE:**

**Create Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.hms_bbr_group_user
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    group_id integer,
    parent_id integer,
    jid character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT hms_bbr_group_user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.hms_doctor
(
    jid character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    mobile character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    operatorid integer,
    designationid integer NOT NULL,
    departmentid integer NOT NULL,
    pager character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    mcr character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_by character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_date timestamp without time zone,
    updated_by character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    updated_date timestamp without time zone,
    escalation_status integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    transport_type integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    extension character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    hospitalid integer NOT NULL,
    type character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'doctor'::character varying,
    title character varying(35) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    subdeptid integer,
    sectionid integer,
    groupid integer,
    location character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    privacy_status integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    remote_status integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    display_priority integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1000,
    fax character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    divisionid integer,
    subsectionid integer,
    unitid integer,
    physical_location_id integer,
    areas_of_interest text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT hms_doctor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (jid)
)
```

Comment: Remember, the select list expressions need to be functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms, otherwise, the SQL is not really valid, even if your database allows it.  Please add (to the question) the `CREATE TABLE` statements for each table, along with all related constraints.  No pictured please.  Post the text of these statements.

Comment: I went ahead and added both `CREATE TABLE` if that help with anything. `hms_doctor` is a bit long but I only need one column there for the left join.

Comment: constraints also added

Comment: Thank you. Now that we see that `id` is the `primary key` of `hms_bbr_group_user`, that means there is only one row in each group from that table.  Which values in the result did you not expect?  **Each group has exactly one parent_id**, so `MAX(hbgu.parent_id)` is not really doing anything.  Add `COUNT(DISTINCT hbgu.parent_id)` to the select list to see this.

Comment: I'll show the important detail in an answer.  This has nothing to do with the JOIN or the hms_doctor table.

Comment: Once the answer is understood, the next step is to determine your real requirement.  Can you ask a new question with the underlying requirement?  What was your ultimate goal?

Comment: I am not quite sure by what you mean by my ultimate goal. My intention is to select only the highest value of `parent_id` without duplicates of `jid`. Meaning that in a correct `SELECT` that I want, `parent_id = 113` is not showing up.

Comment: That's not a clear requirement.  Let me guess... For each `jid`, select the row which contains the greatest `parent_id`.  Is this correct?  I'll update the answer below with SQL to address that requirement.  Let me know if that resolves your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to address the new requirement:**

[Working test case / fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a4167d1bf8db24123148d01bfa3bb3ed)

```
WITH grps AS (
       SELECT jid, MAX(parent_id) AS max_parent
         FROM hms_bbr_group_user
        GROUP BY jid
     )
SELECT hbgu.jid
     , hbgu.id
     , hbgu.group_id
     , hbgu.parent_id
  FROM hms_bbr_group_user AS hbgu
  JOIN grps
    ON grps.jid = hbgu.jid
   AND grps.max_parent = hbgu.parent_id
;
```

**The result:**

[image]

If the above is correct, the next step is to simply add a `JOIN` with the `doctor` table.

**Updated fiddle with doctor detail**

[Updated Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a2b635af7da2066b83793f3a0d267bd8)

**Answer with doctor detail:**

```
WITH grps AS (
       SELECT jid, MAX(parent_id) AS max_parent
         FROM hms_bbr_group_user
        GROUP BY jid
     )
SELECT hbgu.jid
     , hbgu.id
     , hbgu.group_id
     , hbgu.parent_id
     , d.name
  FROM hms_bbr_group_user AS hbgu
  JOIN grps
    ON grps.jid = hbgu.jid
   AND grps.max_parent = hbgu.parent_id
  JOIN hms_doctor AS d
    ON d.jid = grps.jid
;
```

**The result with doctor detail:**

[image]

**Initial answer explaining the OP's original query result:**

This is a simple functional dependence issue.

Since `id` is the `primary key` of the table, when we `GROUP BY` that column, there can be only one row per group (from that table) and only one `parent_id` per group.

**The query:**

```
SELECT hbgu.jid
     , hbgu.id AS id
     , hbgu.group_id
     , MAX (hbgu.parent_id) AS parent_id
     , hbgu.jid
  FROM hms_bbr_group_user hbgu
 WHERE hbgu.group_id = 113
 GROUP BY hbgu.id
;
```

Note: `MAX` was not necessary, since there's guaranteed to be only one `parent_id` value per group, based on the `primary key` being in the `GROUP BY` terms.

```
SELECT hbgu.jid
     , hbgu.id AS id
     , hbgu.group_id
     , hbgu.parent_id
     , hbgu.jid
  FROM hms_bbr_group_user hbgu
 WHERE hbgu.group_id = 113
 GROUP BY hbgu.id
;
```

For both of the above, the result is:

[image]

**The setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.hms_bbr_group_user
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    group_id integer,
    parent_id integer,
    jid character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT hms_bbr_group_user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO hms_bbr_group_user VALUES
   (1, 113, 113, 'jhadmin')
 , (2, 113, 114, 'jhadmin')
;

CREATE TABLE public.hms_doctor
(
    jid character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO hms_doctor VALUES
    ('jhadmin', 'Doctor jhadmin')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue, you made the group by `id` and  `name` (`GROUP BY hbgu.id, d.name`)
so we can see that you have 2 groups first is when `id =1`  and second when `id = 2`  and under the `parent_id` column got the max value of `parent_id` in the group when `id` is 1  and the second one when `id` is 2 if you will remove from the group by `hbgu.id` field you will get one row and `parent_id` will be 114.
Just  `MAX (hbgu.parent_id) AS parent_id`  is not a condition, this means to choose the maximum value of selected `parent_id` by the condition which you had set